# LoadLibrary, a way to instantiate a class from external dll?

Tags: delphi

I have written a dll in d-7. It functions correctly. It gets loaded when an application starts and unloaded when it exists.

Now, that dll must also work on the server side of that application, being loaded from the COM+ surrogate (dllhost.exe) as the server is based on com+ technology.

The problem is that one process may have only one handle for loaded library. I cannot have separate handles on each LoadLibrary call.

In com+, one dllhost.exe can serve many clients, which means that if I load an external library it gives the same instance for each clients calls.

So:

1) Is it possible to somehow workaround this problem?

2) Or Is it possible to directly create instance of the class which resides in this dll for each client call?

3) Or How to make a dll thread-safe by instantiating an internal class for each call.

Thanks for suggestions in advance!

Comment: You have a single global instance now? If so, you need each client to have its own instance. Very hard to give more advice without knowing more details. But basically if you get rid of your globals you will be most of the way there.

Comment: No, I don't have globals. Just create an instance of the class. Each unique call to dll method should operate on its instance of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Since a DLL uses the local memory of the thread/process that calls it, I'm not sure you're really going to have a "problem".  You do not want to have the DLL maintain some global information because that will only lead to threading nightmares.

If you have a function within the DLL return an object reference (effectively a handle) you can also guarantee that each instance gets its own information to play with and not stomp on other processes or threads.  Define the function to return your TWhatever object, have the DLL create it ( TWhatever.Create() ) and return it to the calling process.  It would then be up to the calling process to free the object.  If you need COM+ compatibility then it should be possible to use an interface reference (IWhatever) and return that from your function.

If each thread deals with its own object instance (or interface reference) then you could have the DLL serve as many threads and processes as you wish.

Your question is confusing to me so I'm not sure if I answered it correctly.  :p

Comment: I have in a dll one big class. I don't have global variables. And Now I would like to operate on per-thread instance of that class. This instances should be managed in a dll library. So, Can i distinguish the thread from the dll and create an instance for it if it hasn't been?

Comment: Getting the DLL to manage all instances of the class should be easy.  You will need to keep track of which calling process creates each object reference (getting the current process ID during the call will work).  That way, when the process detaches from the DLL you can free the resources allocated by that process.  Otherwise, the memory will be tied up until the DLL is completely unloaded (a memory leak of sorts).

Comment: Forgot one thing.  Each thread has an ID associated with it.  You will need to record that as well as the process ID for each instance the the class created so you can track each object on a per-thread basis instead of just by process.  Hope that helps and sorry for the omission.  You could use the Windows GetCurrentThreadId() API to get the current thread ID.  You might not need to store the process ID with the thread ID, but it wouldn't hurt.